# Нужна ли тут запятая? .

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "просто" в предложении "И просто(,)для хорошего человека"?

Comment: А о чём это? О "просто хорошем человеке", для которого что-то можно, или что-то можно "сделать просто так" (просто = просто так), напр. для хорошего человека. Нужен контекст, здесь даже предложение неполное - без сказуемого.

Comment: О "просто хорошем человеке".

Comment: Тогда не нужна.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Приведите предыдущий текст, так как это неполное предложение. Смысл его неясен, а от смысла зависит постановка запятой. Например: Мне не трудно сделать это для друга, знакомого. И просто, для хорошего человека. В этом случае возможна авторская запятая с присоединительным значением, выделительная способность сочетания при обособлении увеличивается.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Просто - усилительная частица, запятой не отделяется.